# Transparent NavBar Still Showing

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, iphone-x

So I have am trying to make a transparent navBar similar to this youtube video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pjz_KU89FSY

However for some reason when I follow the steps my navBar turns out like this

[image]

Which continues over into the rootVC to really destroy my view and my UI.
This is my viewDidLoad in the VC that controls it. I don't know what would be the problem tbh

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    setupVc()
}
```

Comment: try with viewWillAppear or viewWillDisappear once

Comment: did exactly this and works for me. the `navigatonBar` stays transparent even after pushing and popping.

Comment: there doesn't seem to be any problem in your code. firstly why is the `navigationBar` solid white? it's not even `translucent`! Anyways, look at other things. Start with storyboard and check if you have a `navigationBar`/`navigationItem` in the hierarchy. Then we'll see what's next.

Comment: i mean its all done programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make your `Navbar` transparent -

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
 self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
                self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            }
```

Comment: where did you put it? in your rootVc or else where?

Comment: the vc that contains the navBar that i am trying to change

Comment: Put it in your custom Navigation controller and set the class name and 
 make sure to set the class name CustomNavigationController from identity inspector

Comment: doing everything programatically bro

Comment: i know. in your video there is acustom navigation controller and he sets the class name same. so do check it. you are not putting your code in correct place i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set navigationBar's barTint color and background color to clear color.

```
enter coself.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = truede here
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .clear
```